# PHPでWebPushを送信したい

Tags: php, push-notification

### 環境

- Windows 10
- Firefox (Developer Edition)
- php 7.4

### 質問

以下のサイトを参考に、PHPとJS（Svelte）を組み合わせて、WebPushの実装を行おうとしております。
[WEBアプリでプッシュ通知を実装する](https://zukucode.com/2020/05/webpush-javascript-php.html)

上記サイトで出てきました、web-push-phpというライブラリを利用しようと
https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php

```php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush;
use Minishlink\WebPush\Subscription;

// ここのキーは https://web-push-codelab.glitch.me/ で取得したものを利用しています
const PUBLIC_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const PRIVATE_KEY = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy';

$result = [DBから取得した値（JSのpushManager.subscribeで取得された、endpoint, p256dh, authが保存されています）]

$auth = array(
    'VAPID' => array(
        'subject' => 'http://localhost:8080',           // 自身のWEBサイトのURL（'http://localhost'など）
        'publicKey' => PUBLIC_KEY,                      // 取得したPublicKey
        'privateKey' => PRIVATE_KEY,                    // 取得したPrivateKey
    ),
);

$webPush = new WebPush($auth);

$webPush->sendNotification(
    $result['endpoint'],                  // 登録したendpoint
    'プッシュ通知のテストです。',           // プッシュ通知に表示する文言
    $result['p256dh'],                    // 登録したuserPublicKey
    $result['auth']                       // 登録したuserAuthToken
);

$webPush->flush();
```

しかし、`sendNotification`というメソッドがない、とエラーが発生いたします。

ですので、以下のようにコードを書き換えました。

```php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush;
use Minishlink\WebPush\Subscription;

// ここのキーは https://web-push-codelab.glitch.me/ で取得したものを利用しています
const PUBLIC_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const PRIVATE_KEY = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy';

$result = [DBから取得した値（JSのpushManager.subscribeで取得された、endpoint, p256dh, authが保存されています）]

$auth = Subscription::create([
    'endpoint' => $result['endpoint'],
    'publicKey' => $result['p256dh'],
    'authToken' => $result['auth']
    ]);

$webPush = new WebPush();
$webPush->queueNotification(
    $auth
);

$report = $webPush->flush();
var_dump($report);
```

しかし、通知は送信されていないのか`var_dump($report);`で空のオブジェクトが返ってきます。

こちらはどのようにして実装するのでしょうか？
ご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示頂けますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

できましたので、記事を書きました。
そちらを共有しておきます。
https://zenn.dev/nnahito/articles/fd2c8b0ad0d19a

Comment: 他のサイトに答えが書かれている場合でも、要点を回答内に記載し、リンクはあくまで参考情報にとどめてください。リンク先が変更・削除された場合に回答の価値が失われることも防ぎます。